# Skewness of fitted mixture not correct?

Tags: r, skewness, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I fitted a gaussian mixture to my financial data.

The values are:

$\pi= 0.3$

$\mu_1= -0.01$

$\mu_2= 0.01$

$\sigma_1=0.01$

$\sigma_2=0.03$

One can see, that both single distributions have a mean of almost zero, wherease one has a high volatility and the other a low volatility. The normal distribution 1, the green one with the high peak has the parameters $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ and occurs (this is pi from output of normalmixEM) with a probability of 0.39. The normal distribution 2 with the smaller peak and the higher volatility has the parameters $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$ and a probability of $1-0.39$.

I imagine the generating of the mixture density as follows:

We have a distribution which is quite probable ($\pi=1-0.39)$ and has $\mu_2$., if the mixture density is done, we "add" a second distribution which is a bit shifted to the left (this one occurs with a probability of 0.39 and has a negative mean). Since the distribution we add lies a bit more to the left I would expect, that the mixture density has a negative skew, since the left tail of the resulting mixture will be heavier?

I control this, which gives a positive skew of `0.7`. Now my question is: Why? I would expect a negative skew, since I thought the mixture density will have a a fatter left tail, since we add to the probable distribution with positive mean a second distribution which is a bit shifted to the left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is time to start paying attention to the answers you receive:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/54734

> It has been largely discussed the validity of using a measure of skewness in **multimodal** distributions, **since its interpretation becomes unclear**. This is the case of finite mixtures. If your mixture looks (or is) unimodal, then you can use this value to understand a bit how asymmetric it is.

In addition, note that MLE is based on maximising the likelihood, not on matching moments.

Check the following example using a simulated sample from a skew-normal (the sample skewness and the skewness of the mixture are different).

```
library(sn)
library(moments)
library(mixtools)

set.seed(4321)    
samp <- rsn(1000,0,1,10)

skewness(samp)

mix<-normalmixEM(samp,k=2,fast=TRUE)

# Sampling from a 2-gaussian mixture
gaussmix <- function(n,m1,m2,s1,s2,alpha) {
    I <- runif(n)<alpha
    rnorm(n,mean=ifelse(I,m1,m2),sd=ifelse(I,s1,s2))
}

# A simulated sample
samp2 <- gaussmix(100000,mix$mu[1],mix$mu[2],mix$sigma[1],mix$sigma[2],mix$lambda[1])

skewness(samp2)
```

**Update**

The measure of skewness based on the third moment is driven by the tails, rather than the level of asymmetry of the distribution. For example, a Student-$t$ distribution with $\nu<3$ degrees of freedom has undefined skewness in spite of being clearly symmetric. For this reason, it is preferred to use a quantile-based measure of skewness. An example of this of this is the [AG measure](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2684808) of skewness which can be defined for any unimodal distribution $F$ as

$$AG=1-2F(\mbox{mode}).$$

This can be estimated by using a nonparametric estimator of $F$, such as a kernel estimator as follows

```
rm(list=ls())
library(sn)
library(moments)
library(mixtools)

# AG measure of skewness: insert the data and the interval c(minim,maxim) where the mode is located

AG <- function(data,minim,maxim){
n = length(data)
hb = (4*sqrt(var(data))^5/(3*n))^(1/5)

     kn = function(x){
     k = r = length(x)
     for(i in 1:k) r[i] = mean(dnorm((x[i]-data)/hb))/hb
     return(r)
      } 

    mode = optimise(f = kn, interval = c(minim,maxim),maximum = TRUE)$maximum

     KN = function(x){
     k = r = length(x)
    for(i in 1:k) r[i] = mean(pnorm((x[i]-data)/hb))
    return(r)
    } 
    return(1-2*KN(mode))
}


# Simulated sample
set.seed(707)
samp <- rsn(1000,0,1,10)

# AG and moment-based skewness measure of the sample
AG(samp,0,2)
skewness(samp)

mix<-normalmixEM(samp,k=2,fast=TRUE)

# Sampling from a 2-gaussian mixture
gaussmix <- function(n,m1,m2,s1,s2,alpha) {
    I <- runif(n)<alpha
    rnorm(n,mean=ifelse(I,m1,m2),sd=ifelse(I,s1,s2))
}

# A simulated sample
mix<-normalmixEM(samp,k=2,fast=TRUE)
samp2 <- gaussmix(100000,mix$mu[1],mix$mu[2],mix$sigma[1],mix$sigma[2],mix$lambda[1])

# AG and moment-based skewness measure of the fitted mixture
AG(samp2,0,2)
skewness(samp2)
```

As you can see, the AG measure of skewness is similar for both distributions, as expected.

**The moral of the story is**: The moment-based measure of skewness is NOT the best choice.

The same happens if this measure is applied to your data:

```
library(sn)
library(moments)
library(mixtools)

# AG measure of skewness: insert the data and the interval c(minim,maxim) where the mode is located

AG <- function(data,minim,maxim){
n = length(data)
hb = (4*sqrt(var(data))^5/(3*n))^(1/5)

     kn = function(x){
     k = r = length(x)
     for(i in 1:k) r[i] = mean(dnorm((x[i]-data)/hb))/hb
     return(r)
      } 

    mode = optimise(f = kn, interval = c(minim,maxim),maximum = TRUE)$maximum

     KN = function(x){
     k = r = length(x)
    for(i in 1:k) r[i] = mean(pnorm((x[i]-data)/hb))
    return(r)
    } 
    return(1-2*KN(mode))
}



# AG and moment-based skewness measure of the sample
AG(dat,-.1,.1)
skewness(dat)

# Sampling from a 2-gaussian mixture
gaussmix <- function(n,m1,m2,s1,s2,alpha) {
    I <- runif(n)<alpha
    rnorm(n,mean=ifelse(I,m1,m2),sd=ifelse(I,s1,s2))
}

# A simulated sample
mix<-normalmixEM(dat,k=2,fast=TRUE)
samp2 <- gaussmix(100000,mix$mu[1],mix$mu[2],mix$sigma[1],mix$sigma[2],mix$lambda[1])

# AG and moment-based skewness measure of the fitted mixture
AG(samp2,-.1,.1)
skewness(samp2)
```

Comment: Updated to show that the problem here is the moment-based measure of skewness since this is NOT an interpretable measure of skewness.

Comment: @Repo thanks man! An answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54736/standard-error-of-normalmixem-fit woulb be great too!

Comment: A deposit in my bank account would be great as well! Just kidding, let me have a look, no promises.