# Finding the expected value of two normal random variables

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, mean, expected-value

Suppose $a_1 = b + c_1$ and $a_2 = 2b + c_2$ where $b, c_1, c_2$ are all $N(0,1)$

Find $E[b|a_1,a_2]$

My attempt:
As $E[b] = 0$, I assume $E[b|a_1, a_2] = 0$. Is this a logical assumption?

Comment: Hint: when you know $a_2$ and $a_1,$ you also know $a_2-a_1$ via subtraction. What information does that give you about $b$?

Comment: `Is this a logical assumption?` No, a _conditional_ mean such as $E[b\mid a_1, a_2]$ is not necessarily equal to the _unconditional_ mean $E[b]$.

Comment: I think a better way to do this is to apply law of total expectation in reverse and work out the joint distribution of a1 and a2?

Comment: This is the second homework problem you've posted today... Neither had much of an "attempt".

Answer (score 1):

Let $B,C_1,C_2$ be independent $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ random variables. Define $A_1=B+C_1$ and $A_2=2B+C_2$. Since we are conditioning on the same information, and $C_1$ and $C_2$ have the same distribution, by symmetry we have
$$
  \mathrm{E}[C_1\mid A_1,A_2] = \mathrm{E}[C_2\mid A_1,A_2]
$$
almost surely (we haven't used the independence assumption yet). Hence,
$$
  \mathrm{E}[B\mid A_1,A_2] = \mathrm{E}[B\mid A_1,A_2] + \mathrm{E}[C_2\mid A_1,A_2] - \mathrm{E}[C_1\mid A_1,A_2]
$$
$$
  = \mathrm{E}[B+C_2-C_1\mid A_1,A_2] = \mathrm{E}[A_2-A_1\mid A_1,A_2]
$$
$$
  = \mathrm{E}[A_2\mid A_1,A_2] - \mathrm{E}[A_1\mid A_1,A_2] = A_2 - A_1 = B+C_2-C_1
$$
almost surely. Therefore (Why? Remember the independence assumption and use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). What is the distribution of $-C_1$?),
$$
  \mathrm{E}[B\mid A_1,A_2]\sim \mathrm{N}(0,3) \, .
$$

(If you have any doubts about $\mathrm{E}[B\mid A_1,A_2]$ being a random variable, [check this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38700/conditional-expectation-of-multivariate-distributions/38707#38707).)